# How to use the count function of Xpath in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to count how many times a node appears in my xml and store this number in a variable:

```
<?php 

$xmlStr = file_get_contents('books.xml'); 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr); 

$res = $xml->xpath("count(catalog/book)");
print_r($res); 

?>
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk102">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
    <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk103">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
    <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
  society in England, the young survivors lay the 
  foundation for a new society.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk104">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
    <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk105">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
    <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
  battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
  Oberon's Legacy.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk106">
    <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
    <title>Lover Birds</title>
    <genre>Romance</genre>
    <price>4.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
    <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
  conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk107">
    <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
    <title>Splish Splash</title>
    <genre>Romance</genre>
    <price>4.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
    <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
  thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk108">
    <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
    <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
    <genre>Horror</genre>
    <price>4.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
    <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
  centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk109">
    <author>Kress, Peter</author>
    <title>Paradox Lost</title>
    <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
    <price>6.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
    <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
  Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
  of being quantum.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk110">
    <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
    <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>36.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
    <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
  detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk111">
    <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
    <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>36.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
    <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
  detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
  SAX and more.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk112">
    <author>Galos, Mike</author>
    <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>49.95</price>
    <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
  looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
  integrated into a comprehensive development 
  environment.</description>
</book>
</catalog>
```

The following will print out an array of the books onscreen:

```
<?php 

$xmlStr = file_get_contents('books.xml'); 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr); 

$res = $xml->xpath("/catalog/book");
print_r($res); 

?>
```

I just cannot figure out why the count function does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are using SimpleXml, which is for "simple" UseCases. If you want to return typed results from an XPath query, you have to use [`DOMXPath::evaluate`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `count()` directly on `$res` instead of applying it inside the xpath.

```
echo count($res);
```

The reason for this is that xpath returns an array of type `SimpleXMLElement`, which contains all the nodes at the xpath argument path.

Comment: Nice that works, it gives me a count of how many books there are! But I am thinking ahead to when I assign authors id's, an author can appear twice do you know how I could count how many distinct authors there would be? Thanks!!!

Comment: You can get the array of authors and then filter the array using `array_unique`

Comment: Ashwin can you point me in the direction of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: `$authors = Array_unique($authors)` where $authors contains all the authors.

Answer (score 4):

SimpleXML unfortunately does not support any XPath queries that ***do not return a nodeset***. Consider using count() on the resulting array instead.